# Ajuda com switch case no JS usando option no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, bom dia!

Estou fazendo um código para praticar switch case no JS mas não estão funcionando, por algum motivo está indo direto para o default, alguém poderia por gentileza me ajudar a resolver o problema?

Primeiro as linha de HTML

```js
function calcular(){
    var nbrtxt1 = document.getElementById('nbrtxt1');
    var n1 = Number(nbrtxt1.value);

    var nbrtxt2 = document.getElementById('nbrtxt2');
    var n2 = Number(nbrtxt2.value);

    var res = document.getElementById('res');

    var operslct = document.getElementById('operador');
    
    var oper = String(operslct.value);
    
    
    switch(oper){
        case 0: 
            oper == 'adicao';
            var soma = n1 + n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} + ${n2} = ${soma}`;
            break

        case 1: 
            oper == 'subtração';
            var sub = n1 - n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} + ${n2} = ${sub}`;
            break

        case 2: 
            oper == 'multiplicacao';
            var mult = n1 * n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${mult}`;
            break
        
        case 3: 
            oper == 'divisao';
            var div = n1 / n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${div}`;
            break

        case 4: 
            oper == 'modulo';
            var modu = n1 % n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${modu}`;
            break

        case 5: 
            oper == 'potencia';
            var pot = n1 % n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${pot}`;
            break


        default:
            res.innerHTML = `[ERRO] Operação inválida`;
    }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Testando funções</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        
        <h1>Teste com funções</h1>

        <input type="number" name="nbrtxt1" id="nbrtxt1" placeholder="Digite um número: ">

        <select name="operador" id="operador">

            <option value="adicao"> <strong> + </strong> </option>

            <option value="subtracao"> <strong> - </strong> </option>

            <option value="multiplicacao"> <strong> * </strong> </option>

            <option value="divisao"> <strong> / </strong> </option>

            <option value="modulo"> <strong> % </strong> </option>

            <option value="potencia"> <strong> ^ </strong> </option>


        </select>

        <input type="number" name="nbrtxt2" id="nbrtxt2" placeholder="Digite outro número: ">

        <input type="button" value= " = " id ="resbutton" name="resbutton" onclick="calcular()">

        <div id="res">Resultado</div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: isso acontece porque está fazendo o `switch` com o valor do campo "operador". Os valores que estão no html (os options) são "adicao", "subtracao", etc mas no `case` está comparando com 0,1, etc... tente fazer o `case` com os valores do html, por exemplo `case "adicao"`

Answer (score -2):

Como você utilizou o ÍNDICE das operações, usa-se o 'selectedIndex' e não 'value'.

Veja trecho de código funcionando abaixo.

Espero ter ajudado!

Caso tenha solucionado o seu problema não esqueça de marcar +1 (setinha para cima) e escolher a minha resposta.

```js
function calcular(){
    var nbrtxt1 = document.getElementById('nbrtxt1');
    var n1 = Number(nbrtxt1.value);

    var nbrtxt2 = document.getElementById('nbrtxt2');
    var n2 = Number(nbrtxt2.value);

    var res = document.getElementById('res');

    var operslct = document.getElementById('operador');
    
    
    /*
    * Como você utilizou o ÍNDICE das operações, usa-se o 'selectedIndex' e não 'value'
    */
    // var oper = String(operslct.value); // <---- você estava utilizando value (errado)
    var oper = operslct.selectedIndex; // <--- utilizando o selected index (correto para o seu exemplo)
    
    
    switch(oper){
        case 0: 
            oper == 'adicao';
            var soma = n1 + n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} + ${n2} = ${soma}`;
            break

        case 1: 
            oper == 'subtração';
            var sub = n1 - n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} + ${n2} = ${sub}`;
            break

        case 2: 
            oper == 'multiplicacao';
            var mult = n1 * n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${mult}`;
            break
        
        case 3: 
            oper == 'divisao';
            var div = n1 / n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${div}`;
            break

        case 4: 
            oper == 'modulo';
            var modu = n1 % n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${modu}`;
            break

        case 5: 
            oper == 'potencia';
            var pot = n1 % n2;
            res.innerHTML = `O resultado de ${n1} * ${n2} = ${pot}`;
            break


        default:
            res.innerHTML = `[ERRO] Operação inválida`;
    }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Testando funções</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        
        <h1>Teste com funções</h1>

        <input type="number" name="nbrtxt1" id="nbrtxt1" placeholder="Digite um número: ">

        <select name="operador" id="operador">

            <option value="adicao"> <strong> + </strong> </option>

            <option value="subtracao"> <strong> - </strong> </option>

            <option value="multiplicacao"> <strong> * </strong> </option>

            <option value="divisao"> <strong> / </strong> </option>

            <option value="modulo"> <strong> % </strong> </option>

            <option value="potencia"> <strong> ^ </strong> </option>


        </select>

        <input type="number" name="nbrtxt2" id="nbrtxt2" placeholder="Digite outro número: ">

        <input type="button" value= " = " id ="resbutton" name="resbutton" onclick="calcular()">

        <div id="res">Resultado</div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Allan muito obrigado, testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, antes de usar o switch, usei if e estava funcionando sem problemas também, vou continuar praticando aqui, novamente muito obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoAlexandreRibeiro, fico feliz em ter ajudado. Não esqueça de clicar em +1 em minha resposta além de marcar ela como escolhida se resolveu o seu problema.

Comment: @RodrigoAlexandreRibeiro, acho que você se equivocou e marcou -1, que indica que você não gostou da  minha resposta, se esse foi o caso tudo bem, porém, se você gostou da resposta, peço que clique na setinha para cima e marque a mesma como escolhida usando a setinha verde.

Comment: pelo contrário eu gostei mas como minha conta é bem recente não consigo avaliar por enquanto, preciso de +15 de reputação, no meu caso por enquanto não consigo atribuir nem positivo e nem negativo na avaliação, perdão pela demora no prazo da resposta